# Fedora 29 (kernel 4.19) occational Wifi problems - cannot establish new connections

Tags: linux, fedora, iwlwifi

Recently I'm having strange Wifi problems (Fedora 29, updated regularly, kernel 4.19.10-300, Dec 17,  Dell Latitude E5470 laptop with Intel wifi).

I cannot establish new connections to my Wifi router (cheap device supplied by my ISP. nmap claims this is an ADB device running OpenWrt Linux 3.3). Pinging the router I get no answer.

*However* an existing SSH connection to a remote machine (obviously traversing through the Wifi router) is still alive and working normally. Other devices (my cellphone) work normally too.

Googling a bit I found a **solution**: clearing the ARP cache using `sudo ip neigh flush dev wlp1s0` solves the problem and restores connectivity. The SSH connection remains connected.

I have no idea why this works and how can I avoid the problem.

My Fedora box is configured to use a static IP address and a static DNS address (Google's 8.8.8.8)

The ARP cache looks the same before, during and after the problem is resolved. The router's MAC address is listed correctly and marked REACHABLE.  No messages appear in the kernel log.

Comment: The leases are shifting. Something is odd in this story, or you are not telling us the full details. Configuring static DHCP leases  probably makes it go away. Another possibility is longer leases, like 4 week leases.

Comment: I'm using a static IP address outside the range of addresses allocated by the router.  The ARP cache looks good. It must be something else that is affected by the command. What other details I should be looking into?

Comment: Hostname shifting, machines with duplicate ip address waking up